# If button is clicked change variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

What am I doing wrong? If the button is clicked, variable s will have a value of 10, if not, it's 0. It's not working though.

```
$('button').observe('click', function () {
  var clicked = true;
  window.clicked = clicked;
});

if (clicked)
{
    var s = 10;
}
else 
{
    var s = 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might help you-

```
    <button>
    click
    </button>

<script>
       var clickCounter=0;
        var s=0;
        alert(s);
        $('button').on('click',function(){
          var s=10;
            alert(s);
            });
</script>
```

Initially the variable will store value of 0, after the vutton is clicked the variable is assigned with value of 10.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks. Although it didn't do as I wanted entirely because  var s=10; inside the function needed to be without 'var'.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a variable S inside the if and else scope.
Create a var s outside of the if and else and assign afterwards

Or you can do it like this:

```
   var s = 0;    
   $('button').observe('click', function () {
      s = 10;
   });
```

This way you assign 10 to s only after click. The code you had before would never set anything to 10

Answer (score 1):

What exactly are you trying to achieve? Why don't you just set `s = 10` on click event? Like this:

```
var s = 0;

$('button').click(function () {
  s = 10;
  console.log(s);
});

console.log(s);
```

Or, if you're trying to observe the value that changes, try something like this:

```
$('button').click(function () {
  object.s = 10;
});

var object = {};
Object.defineProperty(object, 's', {
  get: function() { 
    return this.value; 
  },
  set: function(newValue) {
    alert(newValue);
    this.value = newValue; 
  }
});

object.s = 0;
```